# making Intellij auto-complete protractor's objects

Tags: intellij-idea, protractor

how can I make Intellij to recognize objects like: element, browser, protractor.
and give me auto-complete (intellisense)?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is some support. Check this page:

http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2013/11/enjoy-typescript-in-webstorm/

There is one for protractor:

https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/angular-protractor

Comment: Second (github) link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use typescript definitions in [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/). Its work fine in .js files!

See the sample:

[image: view method documentation on editing code]

To make this, follow tutorial:

1. Download the [protractor definition](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angular-protractor/angular-protractor.d.ts)
2. Reference it in your tests files, like this:

   /// < reference path="path/angular-protractor.d.ts" />

Just it.

Or use [TSD tool](https://github.com/Definitelytyped/tsd#readme) to install and manager your definitions files.